# How to use Distinct OR Group by with Inner Join?

Tags: mysql, sql

have a problem with sql query, simple one but though I'm sitting on it 3d day and cant figure out what is wrong, please help.

Table 1:
[image]

Table 2

[image]

Result
[image]

Desired result - in my reslt I want to display each portfolio ID ONLY ONCE.

sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `portfolio`.`id`, `Description`,`Title`, `portfolio_images`,`Date_created`
FROM `portfolio`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `portfolio_images` ON `portfolio_images`.`portfolio_id` = `portfolio`.`id`
```

Any ideas / solutions are welcomed. Thank you

Comment: "have a problem with sql query" -- First of all you have a problem with posting a good question. Never post tables as images. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements as **text** no screenshots or other images. And then you didn't tell what the `portfolio_images` column should display if there are multiple images. So you should also show your desired output, as tabular **text** no images. You can [edit] the question to improve it.

Comment: @stickybit I thought that images are more clear for someone who is not familiar with DB structure as well as portfolio_images column should display only one image (the first one for every portfolio.id) it is not crucial in this case

Comment: In table 2, you have 2 entries causing duplicates in JOIN. If case of conflict which record will take preference? 

You can use row_number function to select a unique record

Comment: You were mistaken. The database structure is more clear for those unfamiliar with the database structure. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Let's imagine somebody wants to help you and has a solution for your problem in mind. However they're not a 100% certain. So they decide to run a test. But for that they need a test setup. If you provide images of table, they're forced to type everything and might lose their interest in helping you. That's one reason why you never post images of tables (or code) in your own interest. And you want rather to address people familiar with database if you seek help on a database issue. After all someone who hasn't got a clue about it is less likely to help you, aren't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT p.*, pi.*
FROM `portfolio` LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT pi.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY portfolio_id ORDER BY portfolio_id) as seqnum
      FROM portfolio_images pi
     ) pi
     ON pi.portfolio_id = p.id AND seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

In older versions, if you want just one column from `portfolio_images` you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select pi.portfolio_images
        from portfolio_images pi
        where pi.portfolio_id = p.id
        limit 1
       ) as portfolio_images
from portfolio p;
```

As for your query, `DISTINCT` applies to *all* columns, so clearly different columns have different values, even if the columns from `portfolio` are the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, now I get my mistake with trying to use DISTINCT. Though I've tried your solution and got an error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY `portfolio_id` ORDER BY `portfolio_id`) as seqnum
      FROM port' at line 4
I would be glad to fix it, and think that the problem is an OVER statement, but don't know actually how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! Works as shoould work ! Have a great day.